# About Pythons str class constructor default arguments

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Python `str` class constructor in Python3.5:

```
class str(object='') 
class str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

Does it mean that the default encoding is `utf-8`?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Comment: @vaultah given that his coding example is literally the same as in the docs, I think he/she did consult the documentation - the OP just failed to understand what it meant and is asking for some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that means that the default value for encoding is 'utf-8'.

Also you could check this on: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Answer (score 1):

It is an additional initializer for `str` objects that [is used when an object of type `bytes` (or `byte-like`) is supplied](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) (indicated by the prefix `b'text'`.

It's default value is `utf-8` because the default encoding for Python 3.5 is `utf-8` (and it rocks).

It simply means that if a `bytes` object is passed in, the encoding `utf-8` is going to be used **by default** and the `errors=strict` means that encoding errors will raise a UnicodeError. It essentially issues a call to [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).

You can of course change these if you wish and use [another encoding](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) (like `latin-1`) [or another level of errors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error).